# How do I show the preview image in the background when compositing?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I am compositing in Blender and although I have my backdrop on, I am unable to see a preview of what I am compositing. How do I preview my composite in Blender?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Add a Viewer output from Add Menu(<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) -> Output and connect something to it.

[image]

Use <kbd>V</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to zoom out and in and <kbd>Alt</kbd> + MMB to drag the image around.